# Java restlet file upload using apache commons file upload complying with RFC 5987

Tags: java, web-services, file-upload, restlet, apache-commons-fileupload

I have server program which exposes restful web service using restlet 2.2. there is an API for file uploading and for that I use apache commons file upload library. Application is working fine for files with ASCII names but fails when requested from .Net clients with non ASCII file names and file names with special characters. Eg "*" or "'".

When analysed the packets it seems the multipart upload contains

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename="=?utf-8?B?ODE1IEVuZ2FnZW1lbnQgbcOpZGljYWwucGRm?="; filename*=utf-8''815%20Engagement%20m%C3%A9dical.pdf
```

and as I read this is the correct way. But my server only reads the

```
=?utf-8?B?ODE1IEVuZ2FnZW1lbnQgbcOpZGljYWwucGRm?=
```

and not the "filename*" header.

is there are way I can read the filename* header directly as filename when it is avaialable.